# PayPal Rest API Curl SSL : unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: rest, ssl, curl, paypal

I am working on PayPal Express checkout restapi service.
I complated successfully at sandbox mode but when trying go online curl returns "unable to get local issuer certificate" error. At sandbox i dont get this error.

What i tried!
I tried bind cert file (Latest one from mozilla) in php.ini and curl parameter but nothing change.

Currently my code like this

```
        //Building our NVP string
        $request = http_build_query($requestParams + $params);
        //cURL settings
        $curlOptions = array (
            CURLOPT_URL => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_CAINFO =>'certs/cacert.pem', //CA cert file
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlOptions);
```

Where i am failing ?

Note: I already got API Signature for LIVE from
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_get-api-signature

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem.
Mozilla's certs is failing on live edition.
When i used Facebook's cert it fixed.